# passing value from select to input

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, input

I have a select with 3 values ​​and a hidden input.

```
<select name="selection">
<option>0</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
</select>
<br/>
<input type="hidden" name="hid" value=""/>
```

I would like to pass the option of the select to the value of the hidden input, and at the same time, if I select 0 from the  select, the input type="hidden" become type="text" while maintaining value as 0.

Comment: changing the type of an input does not work in IE

Comment: you cant change the type of input in IE. But you do not have to do that if you show and hide it with css. see example below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### you cant change the type in IE, but you can hide/show it with css.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neysor/4EVBL/)

### HTML

```
<select name="selection" class="box1">
    <option>0</option>
    <option selected>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
<br/>
<input type="text" name="hid" value="" class="box2"/>
```

### JS

```
$(".box1").change(function () {
    var selected = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    $(".box2").val(selected);
    if (selected === "0") {
        $(".box2").show();
    } else {
        $(".box2").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the change event

```
$("select[name='selection']").change(function() {
     var selected = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
     $("input[name='hid']").val(selected);
     if (selected == "0") 
          $("input[name='hid']").attr("type", "text");
     else
          $("input[name='hid']").attr("type", "hidden");
});
```

I advise you to read:
http://api.jquery.com/change/

Here a jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/V4GZ2/